# Automate user last log in information extraction from Azure AD

Tags: azure, powershell, logging, azure-active-directory

I am trying to extract users last log in date time from Azure AD using a PowerShell script. Once  I elevated myself as Global Administrator, it is working as expected. But, I want to automate this process with a scheduled task.

I used,

Connect-AzureAD | Out-Null

to connect to Azure Ad and provided the credentials. But during the automation process this won't work and it will pop up below window all the time to enter the creds.

[image]

Currently I tried granting "Security Reader" permission and but cannot use it as the user account needs to elevate access all the time.

My question is how can I automate this process? Basically I want to connect to Azure AD and extract the user last log in date and time.

Thanks team.

Comment: As Azure AD PowerShell module is going to deprecate soon, it's better switching to Microsoft Graph PowerShell modules. To avoid user interaction or MFA prompts, you can connect to Microsoft Graph with a **service principal**.

Comment: @Sridevi, can you please kindly explain me how to do this with certificate? my compant doesn't allow to use screat and teanent id. Thanks a lot

Comment: Please post a new question including what code you tried to do that with certificate and share question link here.

Comment: Hi @Sridevi, This is the new post. I use the same code as you mentioned below.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77803358/connect-to-microsoft-graph-using-powershell-with-a-certificate-not-using-client.

Comment: I posted answer for that new post. Please check and let me know if it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To avoid user interaction or MFA prompts with pop-up windows, you can connect to Microsoft Graph with a **service principal** by adding permissions to it.

In my case, I registered one application and added below API permissions of **Application** type by granting admin consent:

[image]

To connect to Microsoft Graph as a **service principal**, you can make use of below PowerShell script that does not involve any user interaction:

```
#Install-Module Microsoft.Graph
$ApplicationId = "appId"
$SecuredPassword = "client_secret"
$tenantID = "tenantId"

$SecuredPasswordPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString `
-String $SecuredPassword -AsPlainText -Force

$ClientSecretCredential = New-Object `
-TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential `
-ArgumentList $ApplicationId, $SecuredPasswordPassword

Connect-MgGraph -TenantId $tenantID -ClientSecretCredential $ClientSecretCredential
```

**Response:**

[image]

Now, I ran below PowerShell script and got **last log in date time** of users successfully in response without any pop-up window:

```
$users = Get-MgUser -Property 'SignInActivity'

foreach ($user in $users) {
    $displayName = $user.DisplayName
    $lastSignInDateTime = $user.SignInActivity.LastSignInDateTime

    if ($lastSignInDateTime -eq $null) {
        Write-Host "$displayName has never signed in."
    } else {
        Write-Host "$displayName last signed in on $lastSignInDateTime"
    }
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

**Reference:**
[Connect To Microsoft Graph PowerShell With a Client Secret by **Daniel Bradley**](https://ourcloudnetwork.com/connect-to-microsoft-graph-powershell-with-a-client-secret/)

Comment: Thank you Sri Devi. This is what I am testing atm. This is very clear. I am going to use certificate instead of secret.